# How to superimpose Wood-Saxon and Coulomb potential?

Tags: nuclear-physics, potential

I have just written a simple simulation that models the tunnel-effect of alpha-particles for $^{212}$Po and $^{238}$Ur. In this simulation, I approximate the potential of the nucleus by a simple square well. Now I'm thinking about improving the simple model to a more complex one. My idea is to superimpose the [**Wood-Saxon**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woods%E2%80%93Saxon_potential) potential with the Coulomb-potential. The result should look something like this picture:

[image]

My question is: how do I actually get there? Do I just add the Woods-Saxon and the Coulomb-potential?

**FOLLOW UP**
@dmckee, thanks, it worked and only needed little tweaking. you were absolutely right!

[image]

Comment: Why did you remove the image?

Comment: accident, i wanted to post a follow up. i'll put it back in. thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Do I just add the Woods-Saxon and the Coulomb-potential?"*

Do you know any other way of combining potentials? You certainly do just add them up.

Two complications:

1. You may need to tweak the parameters of your potentials if, for instance, they were set to get a certain $Q$
2. You'll need some kind of charge distribution function for the nucleus (a uniform spherical distribution is not a terrible place to start).

Comment: ;-), thanks for pointing that out. the emphasis should be placed on the **just**. as you have written: there may be complications. thanks!